# how to display only level 0 category into nav magento

Tags: magento

I want to display only 0 level category into navigation, how can I do that ? Is there any setting or I need to change into code ? Currently menu is displayed by `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>` code.

Answer (score 2):

I got this, we can do it by changing in global settings, goto sysytem ->configration->catalog->Category Top Navigation and set "Maximal Depth" to 1 , then save config and clear cache.